# If $s < t$ on $[a, b]$, is it necessary that $\int_{a}^{b}s < \int_{a}^{b}t$ when the definition of an integral is changed?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $s$ be a step function on a real interval $[a, b]$ and take a partition
$\{ a := x_{0} < x_{1} < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_{n} := b \}$ of $[a, b]$ such that for every $1 \leq k \leq n$ there is a real $s_{k}$ such that $s(x) = s_{k}$ for all $x_{k-1} < x < x_{k}$.
Let
$$\int_{a}^{b}s(x)\ dx := \sum_{1}^{n}s_{k}(x_{k}^{2} - x_{k-1}^{2}).$$

If $s < t$ are step functions on $[a, b]$, is it necessary that $\int_{a}^{b}s < \int_{a}^{b}t$?

I guess so because the norm of a partition changing has no effect on the order. But I am not sure of that.

Comment: This is [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), right? I'd guess that notation like $\int s(x) d(x^2)$ is more common for such integrals than $\int s(x) dx$. (But I am not entirely sure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still true.  You want
$$\sum_1^n s_k(x_k^2 - x_{k - 1}^2) < \sum_1^n t_k(x_k^2 - x_{k - 1}^2)$$
to hold.  A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for this to be true is that
$$s_k(x_k^2 - x_{k - 1}^2) < t_k(x_k^2 - x_{k - 1}^2)$$
holds for each $k$.  And this *is* true because $s_k < t_k$ and $x_k^2 - x_{k - 1}^2$ is positive.

This assumes, by the way, that I'm using the same partition for both $s$ and $t$.  But that's ok because I can always lump the boundaries of two different partitions together to get a partition that is a common refinement.

Comment: (In general this holds whenever the integrator is increasing.)